# Open file windows apears in front

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am using this code, and the open file windows apears in the back of all the windows and I want to see it in front of everthing:

```
Tk().withdraw()
df= pd.read_excel(askopenfilename())
```

Comment: Looks like this has been answered already. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892339/how-to-make-a-tkinter-window-jump-to-the-front

Comment: @AlbertoJLorenzoRosario But that question's about how to move the _root window_ to the front, not the _file dialog_. The OP wants to move the _file dialog_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter askopenfilename() won't open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51071984/tkinter-askopenfilename-wont-open)